# Save Ansible Output to a Variable

Tags: ansible

For the following Ansible Console Output:

```yaml
TASK [Run Ping Command] *********************************
Changed: [HostName]

TASK [Add Ping Command Results to Log] *********************************
ok: [HostName]
```

How would I save the output of `Changed: [HostName]` and `ok: [HostName]` to a variable?

I tried using `register:` but it just saves the output of the command instead of what is printed on the Ansible Console (Changed, ok, skipping..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) would do the trick, those text messages are displayed based on the values received from the result of the task

Assuming that you have the task:

```yaml
- name: Run Ping Command
  ansible.builtin.ping:
  register: ping_result
```

the variable `ping_result` will have the result of the task

```yaml
- name: Task changed
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "task changed"
  when:
    - not ping_result.skipped | default(false)
    - ping_result.changed | default(false)

- name: Task failed
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "task failed"
  when:
    - not ping_result.skipped | default(false)
    - ping_result.failed | default(false)

- name: Task succeeded
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "task succeeded"
  when:
    - not ping_result.skipped | default(false)
    - (not ping_result.failed) | default(false)

- name: Task skipped
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "task skipped"
  when:
    - ping_result.skipped | default(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Ansible Console Output is something which is outside of the playbook itself and generated by [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html), you would need to

- either implement the functionality somehow by your self, in example as [within in the here given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75063415/6771046)
- or [Enable (another) callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#example-callback-plugins) in example [`log_plays` callback – write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html) which can

  > *write playbook output to a file per host in the `/var/log/ansible/hosts` directory*

  and be read later from another playbook again for further processing.